# How to convert .sif file to json to be used in Cytoscape JS

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, file-conversion

I have a .sif file like this

```
NodeA   "phosphorylation"   NodeB
NodeA   "binding"       NodeC
NodeB   "phosphorylation"   NodeC
NodeD   "binding"       NodeC
```

I need this to be converted to JSON which can be consumed by Cytoscape JS to generate a graph using the nodes and their relationships.

The format I need it to be like

```
[
    {"data":{"id":"n40","weight":53},"position":     
    {"x":50,"y":45},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,
    "selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},

    {"data":{"id":"n41","weight":23},"position":     
    {"x":150,"y":45},"group":"nodes","removed":false,
    "selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,
    "grabbable":true,"classes":""},

    ..........................

    {"data":{"id":"e129","weight":31,"source":"n65","target":"n58"},
    "position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,
    "selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},

    {"data":{"id":"e131","weight":90,"source":"n53","target":"n43"},
    "position:{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,
    "selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},
]
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried SIF.js?  I found it on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sif.js

It's not quite the same JSON format as Cytoscape, but you could use it and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the entries just a bit so that they match.  Or you could use the code in [the repo](https://github.com/jmvillaveces/sif.js) to build your own parsing function that directly outputs the [Cytoscape format](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

You can also use the [Cytoscape desktop software](http://cytoscape.org/download.php) to convert SIF to JSON, but that can't be automated as part of a JS app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had to modify this library according to the need. There are some deviations from the format it returns to be used for Cytoscape. But, it was great!